# AWSIOT: RuntimeError: 1033 (AWS_IO_TLS_CTX_ERROR): Failed to create tls context

Tags: python, python-3.8, aws-iot

I recently upgraded the packaged `awsiotsdk` and `awscrt` from versions `1.5.7 -> 1.5.10` and `0.10.8 -> 0.11.4`. After doing so I'm getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: 1033 (AWS_IO_TLS_CTX_ERROR): Failed to create tls context
```

The error is coming from the following function which works in the previous version.

```
awsiot.mqtt_connection_builder.websockets_with_default_aws_signing(...)
```

Any idea what underlying issue might be causing such an error?

Comment: Would you open an issue on the [AWS IoT Device SDK v2 for Python repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/issues) on GitHub?

Comment: Done: https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/issues/188